# how can this query be changed for better enhancement?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How can this query be modified for better enhancement?

```
select * from employee
where emp_id like '0%'
  and emp_id not like '00%'
  or emp_id like '1%'   
  or emp_id = '999';
```

I want all the details of employees with emp_id like '0xxxxxxx' ,'1xxxxxx', 999 but not like '00xxxxxx'.

Comment: what is the problem with your query?

Comment: If you have only a few employees, then performance optimization is not needed.  If you have a whole bunch of employees, then you query will probably return lots and lots of rows, so a full table scan is not much of an issue.

Comment: Before worrying about performance, make sure of using parentheses on your conditions to get the results you want: `(emp_id like '0%' and emp_id not like '00%') or ....`

Comment: Yes, it has lakhs of records.

Comment: when I write emp_id like '0%' and then emp_id not like '00%', it first gets all the rows with 0% and then compares each row with 00% which takes time. Cant this be avoided?

Comment: you have actual issues to solve or this is a preemptive optimization that you think (hope? guess?) may produce any improvement? what are your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of the [regexp_like](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php) function introduced in oracle 10g.

Your statement could look like this in the end

```
select *
from (select '1xxxxx' d from dual union
      select '0xxxxx' d from dual union
      select '00xxxx' d from dual union
      select '999'    d from dual union
      select '9999'   d from dual union
      select '555'    d from dual union
      select '5xxxxx' d from dual)
where regexp_like(d, '(^0[^0]|^1)|^999$');
```

The `|` acts like an or and it reads like, starts with `0` followed by not `0` or starts with 1 or equals 999